# How to convert VMWare Server 2.0.2 VM (Windows Server) to KVM on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, kvm-switch

Given: VMWare Server 2.0.2 virtual machine running 32-bit Windows Server. CPU: AMD Phenom II X6 1075T.

Required: convert and run the VM on KVM (Ubuntu 16.04.5, 64bit, latest updates applied), CPU: Intel Core i5-2400.

Source VM doesn't use specific Phenom instructions missing from the target CPU.

Tried this howto: [Converting a Windows 2008R2 vmdk to a KVM image](https://zacloudbuilder.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/converting-a-windows-2008r2-vmdk-to-a-kvm-image/), and other typical howtos which usually base upon the below command to convert (converts without errors, but fails to start - see below):

```
qemu-img convert -O qcow2 source.vmdk target.qcow2
```

The below was tried, also in vain:

- running under variety of CPUs (coreduo, core2duo, phenom etc)
- running under variety of VGA cards
- trying to run source .vmdk directly

Symptom: after the converted VM is started, its CPU(s) load rises to 100%, the BIOS VNC screen remains at "Booting from harddisk...", nothing else happens.

KVM logs have no errors related to the above, so I have no clues how to handle the task. Any sensible suggestions are quite welcome.

Comment: Boot from a Windows Server CD image and run startup repair.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Tried that, too. chkdsk, fixmbr, fixboot - file systems consistent, partition table - as well, but still not booting.